# Textbook Error?: Closure of the Unit Ball in a Topology whose Basis is all Vertical Lines in the plane

Tags: general-topology

This is example 2.28(c) on p. 41 in *Introduction to General Topology* by Cain. I do not understand how Cain derives his result for $cl(A)$. We are told

$|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

"Let $X$  be the plane, and for each real $x$, let $L_x$ be the vertical line passing through the point $(x,0)$. Define $\mathbf{B}=\{L_x :x\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Since $L_x\cap L_y = \emptyset$ for $x\neq y $, $\mathbf{B}$ is a base for a topology. If $A=\{z=(x,y):|z|<1\}$, then in the topology for which $B$ is a base, we have $cl(A)=\{(x,y):0<x<1\},int(A)=\emptyset,Fr(A)=cl(A)$."

However, it seems to me $cl(A)=\{(x,y):-1<x<1\}$ since we are earlier given:

"Corollary: A point $p$  is a member of $cl(S)$ iff $\forall B\in \mathbf{B}:p\in B,B\cap S\neq \emptyset$"

My reasoning is that, given any point $p=(p_x,p_y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $p_x \in (-1,1)$, there is only 1 $B\in \mathbf {B}$ which contains $p$: $L_{p_x}$, which is an infinite vertical line through the $x$ coordinate of $p$. Since $L_{p_x}$ is an infinite vertical line, it must intersect $A$, meaning $p$ is in $cl(A)$

Am I missing something here, or is the textbook in error?

Comment: You are absolutly right.

Comment: @mfl thanks for confirming this. I'll send Prof. Cain and/or the publisher an e-mail so they can add it to a list of errata.

Comment: Also note that in the solution in the book is not $A\subset \rm{cl}(A).$

Comment: yes, you're right. In view of that, its a really glaring error.